# Hide Elements within Jinja2 template? Any possible way to hide a button?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am working on my web application using Python and Flask. I have got a navbar and some buttons on it and I would like to hide one of buttons when I am not on the index page. Is that possible? I would like the button "select brand" to be visible only on index.html page.

```
{% block navbar %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default fixed-top ">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}" title="Mobile phones and accessories">
                <img style="max-width:40px; margin-top: -9px;"
                     src="http://www.logospng.com/images/38/devfest-2016-38885.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Home</a></li>
                {% if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.admin %}
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('phones.new_phone') }}">Add phone</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('phones.brand') }}">Add brand</a></li>
                {% endif %}

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select brand <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        {% for brand in brands %}
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="{{ url_for('main.index', bra=brand) }}">{{ brand }}</a>
                         {% endfor %}


                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span> {{ current_user.username }}
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}" >Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}" >Login</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}" >Register</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method='POST' action="{{ url_for('phones.search') }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search" type="text" name="search">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: All you have to do is put the button('s) in an if/else block similar to what your doing here "{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}" but instead base it on the page title

Comment: I am not totally familiar with this templating syntax but basically 
{% if filename='index.html' %}
    <button><button/>
{% end if %}
and then you need to set the var filename somewhere in you python code.

Comment: @KyleJoeckel when I run the application I get that error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '='`  I guess it doesn't accept =

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new variable within your `index` route and pass that variable into the `render_template` method of said route. The *presence of this variable will determine if the `<button> or link` within your `<nav>` should be rendered or not*. Since the `<nav>` will be shared across all other layouts, its `HTML` code should be put within your **base layout**, or the *layout which all other views are inheriting from*.

Something along the lines of:

**index route:**

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    # isIndex is the variable we will use to determine 
    # whether or not to render your navigation link or button
    return render_template('index.html', isIndex=True)
```

**base layout file:**

```
  <div class="navbar-nav">
      {% if isIndex %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">linkOnlyForIndexPage</a>
       {% else %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">link1</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">link2</a>
       {% endif %}
  </div>
```

This is exactly what you're already doing with `{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}` for your navigation links. The reason this works is because the **index route is the only route** which **sets this variable, within your jinja2 templates,** so all other routes which render corresponding views will default to false on this conditional check:       `{% if isIndex %}`

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: not sure what i am doing wrong but the link before {% else %} isnt displaying on the Index page, but the links after else are displaying correctly.

Comment: Actually it works!! I had index function in my other file, all i needed to do was to pass the variable isIndex and it works. Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: Np glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

Set the following on your child pages:

```
{% set active_page = "index" %}
```

Then in your base template:

```
{% if active_page == "index" %}
... button html here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am still getting `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '='` error

Comment: Apologies, i missed a '=' from the if statement. See updated post above.